# &xacute in opera is not working

Tags: special-characters, opera, text-rendering

`Compañ&iacuteas`

should display:

> Compañías

and it does in all browsers but Opera, it displays:

```
Compañ&iacuteas
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after the iacute. You should have written: `Compañ&iacute;as`

Comment: Internet Explorer is a bit "forgiving" on these things. Could you please mark my answer as an answer? :)

Comment: Did it already ;) IE whas displaying it OK, but opera no!! :S

Comment: Yes, I know. Much invalid HTML renders fine in IE. That's the problem of using IE to test web pages.... (Another problem is that much valid HTML doesn't render fine in IE, so you have to test it in IE anyway...)